# XML Transfer into HTML Document (XSL)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I can't seem to be able to transfer XML data to a HTML webpage using XSL. It's a University project hence not using other technologies.

XML structure is simple - e.g.

```
<dust2>
  <team>
    <player>
      <name>Xizt</name>
      <team>NiP</team>
      <kills>19</kills>
      <deaths>16</deaths>
      <assists>0</assists>
      <kdr>0.19</kdr>
    </player>
  </team>
</dust2>
```

The real document has 2 `<team>` tags, each with 5 `<player>` within each team. The XML tags are all closed and declared properly to my knowledge.

The lecturer provided us with this script.js file with functions for XML loading, parsing and transformation:

```
// HTTP Request
function loadXML (file) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // Different ActiveXObject for IE
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", file, false);
    try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document";} catch (e) {}; // Set responseType for IE 9+
    xhttp.send(null);
    return xhttp.responseXML;
};

// Process & Output
function processXML (location, xml, xsl) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document" || "ActiveXObject" in window) { // Added criteria for IE detection
        // code for IE
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = ex;
    } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById(location).appendChild(resultDocument);
    };
};

// HTTP Request, Process & Output
function outputXML(location, xmlFile, xslFile) {
    xml = loadXML(xmlFile);
    xsl = loadXML(xslFile);
    processXML(location, xml, xsl);
};

// Parse XML to String
function XMLToString(xml) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // code for IE
        var txt = xml.xml;
        return txt;
    } else {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        var txt = new XMLSerializer();
        txt = txt.serializeToString(xml);
        return txt;
    };
};

// Parse String to XML
function StringToXML(txt) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xml=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
    } else {
        // code for IE
        xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml.async=false;
        xml.loadXML(txt); 
    };
    return xml;
};
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dreamhack Winter 2014 Finals</title>

  <!-- JS Transform - Obtained from lecture material -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadxml() {
      outputXML('dust2', 'xml/dust2nons.xml', 'xml/dust2stats.xsl');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadxml();">
  <p><div id="dust2" onload="outputXML('dust2', 'xml/dust2nons.xml', 'xml/dust2stats.xsl');"></div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My XSL document has changed ump-teen times only be able to get one piece of XML printed on the main page but even using the same technique I can't quite get there. I managed to get the XSL to show static html in the XSL file but no

```
<xsl:for-each select="dust2/team/player">

<xsl:value-of select="name">
```

combinations so far.

Since then I have lost the ability to even transfer static HTML from the XSL document. I'm unsure if even the doctype etc is correct.

My XSL document, `dust2stats.xsl`

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Player</th>
          <th>Kills</th>
          <th>Assists</th>
          <th>Deaths</th>
          <th>KDR</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        eggs
        <xsl:for-each select="dust2/team/player">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="kills" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="assists" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="deaths" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="kdr" />
            </td>
            test1234
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The random words were an attempt at transferring static HTML through. I achieved this at some stage but have regressed since and have lost it.

Any form of guidance or advice would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: Add the relevant source code here (only parts that will help the question). Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Will you at some point return to your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your need to declare stylesheet properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

   [here is your templates]

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you need to declare a root template for your transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      ...
      <tbody>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="dust2/team/player/>
      </tbody>
      ...
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can declare below template for each player:

```
<xsl:template match="player">
    <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>

                    <td><xsl:value-of select="kills"/></td>

                    <td><xsl:value-of select="assists"/></td>

                    <td><xsl:value-of select="deaths"/></td>

                    <td><xsl:value-of select="kdr"/></td>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Not sure about browser xslt processors, but usually it looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The following works pretty well (tested in IE 5+, Chrome, Firefox).

First I rewrote the entire script.js file, because, frankly, it wasn't really nice.

```
function loadXml(url) {
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch (ex) {}
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to create XMLHTTP request object.");
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.responseXML;
}

function transformXml(xml, xsl) {
    var xsltProcessor;
    if (typeof xml === "string") xml = stringToXml(xml);
    if (typeof xsl === "string") xsl = stringToXml(xsl);
    if (window.XSLTProcessor) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        return xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
    } else if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
        return xml.documentElement.transformNode(xsl);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to transform XML.");
    }
}

function xmlToString(input) {
    var str;
    if (window.XMLSerializer) {
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(input);
    } else if (input.xml) {
        return input.xml;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to convert input to string.");
    }
    return str;
}

function stringToXml(input) {
    var xml;
    if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml.async=false;
        xml.loadXML(input);
        return xml;
    } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(input, "text/xml");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to convert input to XML document.");
    }
}

function setElementContent(element, content) {
    element.innerHTML = '';
    if (content.nodeType) { 
        element.appendChild(content);
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = content;
    }
}
```

Now we have these functions:

- `loadXml` - synchronously loads an XML document from a URL and returns it
- `transformXml` - applies and XSL to an XML and returns the result
- `xmlToString` - takes an XML document and returns a string
- `stringToXml` - takes a string and returns an XML document
- `setElementContent` - sets an element's content

Next, your XSL syntax is messed up. Well, theoretically it's valid, but the MSXML processor that IE uses does not understand this particular format. It expects an XML document beginning with `<xsl:stylesheet>` or `<xsl:transform>`.

So we are using this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/dust2">
    <xsl:for-each select="team">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Kills</th>
            <th>Assists</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>
            <th>KDR</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:for-each select="player">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="kills" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="assists" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="deaths" /></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="kdr" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that generatung a full HTML document is unecessary. A fragment (`<table>` in this case) is perfectly fine.

Now that everything is set up, we can use it:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var xml = loadXml('xml/dust2nons.xml'),
          xsl = loadXml('xml/dust2stats.xsl'),
          target = document.getElementById('dust2');

      setElementContent(target, transformXml(xml, xsl));
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="dust2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what `transformXml(xml, xsl)` produces:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th><th>Kills</th><th>Assists</th><th>Deaths</th><th>KDR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Xizt</td><td>19</td><td>0</td><td>16</td><td>0.19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```